# Views - offset when displaying all results?

Tags: 7, views

In a view, either set to "display all results" or "specified number of results" and set to 0, I cannot seem to be able to use the "offset". On the other hand, if I set a number of items, say 100, I can use the offset just fine (I want to hide the first item from the result set). Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Is there any other setting in the view? I am getting the correct result even after setting it to 0 in the Items per page. I hope that is what you mean.

Comment: I need to set offset to 1
when items per page is either "all" or 0 (which works like "all")

Comment: by setting the offset to 1 I need to hide the first item in the result set

Comment: Could you tell me where you are setting this?

Comment: Nevermind, Patrick Kenny already answered correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the way it's designed.  If you set the number of things to be displayed to `display all results` or `0` (which is the same thing), it doesn't make sense to have an offset because you already ordered it to show every single result.

If you want to use an offset, set a specified number of results.  If you don't know what number to set, just pick an arbitrarily high number that you are unlikely to exceed.

**EDIT**: If you just want to hide the first item, is there some way to configure one of the filters so that the item is removed?  That is another possible approach.

Comment: That sounds a tad sloppy though, doesn't it? I mean my scenario *is* indeed a valid one. "Get me all the items. Ommit the first one."

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with the filter approach and maybe i can find something delta-like.

Comment: And it worked, checkmark in 4 minutes. :) I filtered out by nodequeue position in my case. != 1